# How can I prevent 'enter' from being triggered while pasting multi-line text into python terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

I'm trying to run Python code with the input() function, and i want to paste text for the input. However, the text I'm pasting has more than 1 line, and the program runs after just the first line.

This is my code:

```
import re
regex3digit = re.compile(r'(\w\w\w\w)\s(\w\w\w\w)')
regex = regex3digit.findall(input('Paste your text.\n'))
for mo in regex:
    print(mo)
```

This is the result:

```
Paste your text.
So now we have an idea of what insulators and conductors are and how they
('what', 'insu')
```

As you can see, the text got cut off after the first line.